# Is there a way to check if a tsc --watch is running in the current directory

Tags: typescript

I was trying to write a script that would automatically open a tsc --watch terminal window. I'm able to do the opening new window part correctly. However, I'd like to check if a tsc --watch is already running in the current directory and start a new one only if it's not. Is there any way to check for its presence?

Comment: are you on Windows or a Mac or Linux?

Comment: @AlexanderMills I need a solution that can work on both Mac and Windows. I asked a [question](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22284) on the TypeScript repo, in which someone suggested to use [quicklock](https://github.com/ORESoftware/quicklock/blob/master/nodejs.md#advanced-usage). This however doesn't currently work on Windows, even though the maintainer said it's possible to port it to Windows.